# How to send all current params to path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I've got a form that has the option to export to a spreadsheet, but I need the spreadsheet to have the same current params(Filters) as the report in my page.
Something like this:

```
  <a href="<%= reports_orders_path(params, format: 'xlsx') %>">
    <span><i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i></span>
    <%= t '.export_xlsx' %>
  </a>
```

I've managed to do so like this:

```
  <a href="<%= reports_orders_path(
    "by_event" => @event.id.to_s, 
    "by_document" => params[:by_document],
    "by_status" => params[:by_status],
    "by_method" => params[:by_method], 
    "by_date" => params[:by_date], 
    "by_period_init" => params[:by_period_init],
    "by_period_end" => params[:by_period_end],
    format: 'xlsx') %>">
    <span ><i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i></span>
    <%= t '.export_xlsx' %>
  </a>
```

But this feels and looks so messy.

Is there a nicer way to get all current params and apply them to my path?

Comment: If you want to stuff *all* of params as keyword argument into your method, you could do it as `report_orders_path(by_event: @event.id.to_s, format: 'xlsx', **params)`. Requires Ruby 2 or higher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# x_controller.rb
def action
  [...] #your code
  @filters = report_filters
end

def report_filters
  extract_fields = params.keys - ["_method", "authenticity_token", "commit", "controller", "action"] 

  { format: :xlsx, by_event: @event.id }.merge(params.slice(*extract_fields))
end
```

for exemple ?

I absolutely hate helpers because I don't find them maintainable as time passes and are prone to huge technical debt from my experience.

EDIT: Dynamic params extraction

Answer (score 0):

One way to clean up the markup can be to extract the desired params to a view helper, like so:

```
# app/helpers/application_helper.rb

def filter_params
  {
    by_event: @event.id.to_s, 
    by_document: params[:by_document],
    by_status: params[:by_status],
    by_method: params[:by_method], 
    by_date: params[:by_date], 
    by_period_init: params[:by_period_init],
    by_period_end: params[:by_period_end],
    format: 'xlsx'
  }
end
```

Then in the view, call the helper method to populate the params:

```
# app/views/your/view/path.html.erb

<%= link_to reports_orders_path(filter_params) do %>
  <span><i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i></span>
  <%= t '.export_xlsx' %>
<% end %>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: That is a good way to do it! although it remains static, which is not my ideal solution since my app may need more filters and so.

Comment: Oh I see, maybe leveraging `request`'s [query_parameters](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#path-parameters-query-parameters-and-request-parameters) can be helpful.